# Windows Phone 7 Game engines?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, 2d, game-engine

Is there any Windows Phone 7, 2D/3D game engine with any IDE?

Something like that: http://unity3d.com/

Comment: This is really too vague, you need to list features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is something like unity3d which allow you to port in all platforms: http://www.shivaengine.com/

Answer (score 3):

XNA Game Studio ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx

Comment: @62316e: The IDE is Visual Studio 2010.  You need to create your own Sandbox.

Comment: XNA Game Studio is not a "Game Engine". XNA game studio is an extension for visual studio to support XNA Framework (and again, XNA is not game engine, it's a framework). Game engine is something more. There should something like ready to use scene graph, camera, GUI, particles system, classes to work with menus etc.

Comment: oups Sorry I focused on the "IDE" part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Sunburn Engine](http://www.synapsegaming.com/products/sunburn/engine/)? It's appear to be only one commercial level game engine for XNA with middle-ware and WP7 support (at this moment, WP7 is relatively young =) platform)

There was also TorqueX (for XNA), but they still stuck on XNA 3.1 - so no WP7 support.